# Big tiff read and view in Matlab

Tags: matlab, tiff

I have downloaded a btf file (big tiff) from the links below, how can I read it and "imshow" it? is there a way to convert it to tiff format as the btf is not that common?

Link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByhuP_NuuARtSW9aeTdPUTlRdWM/view?usp=drive_web

http://www.photomacrography.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=28990&sid=cca737a2e0bc7ea3e2e41f0d6e75f5a9

I used this code:

```
t = Tiff('d:/Image_687.btf','w8');
imageData = read(t);
```

and got this error:

> Error using tifflib
>   Unable to retrieve PhotometricInterpretation.
>
> Error in Tiff/getTag (line 838)
>                       tagValue = tifflib('getField',obj.FileID,Tiff.TagID.(tagId));
>
> Error in Tiff/read (line 1487)
>               photo = obj.getTag('Photometric');
>
> Error in Untitled2 (line 2)
>   imageData = read(t);

Comment: What code did you try? What error message did you get?

Comment: updated it in the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real issue with your code is the second parameter that you have passed to `Tiff`. As the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiff-class.html) states, the second parameter indicates in what mode to open the file. You have specified `w8` which the documentation states is:

> open TIFF file for writing a BigTIFF file; discard existing contents.

This means that it is deleting your image before you even start! If you want to use the `Tiff` class, you'll want to either use no second parameter or the `r` parameter to open the file for reading.

```
t = Tiff('Image_687.btf');
t = Tiff('Image_687.btf', 'r');
```

That being said, in general it is better to try to load it with a higher level function such as [`imread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html). The Tiff class is a much lower-level function that can be a little harder to manipulate but may provide some needed specialty functionality.

```
 im = imread('Image_687.btf');
 size(im)

     3072   4080   3
```

I had to do a little manipulation for display because the RGB values weren't between 0 and 255

```
im = double(im);
im = uint8(255 * im ./ max(im(:)));
imshow(im);
```

[image: Resulting Image]